# Can't figure out how to reset an int so I can use my loop properly making the game of Pig

Tags: java

When it is the computer's turn I need it to keep going until it reaches 35 points for the current turn but I am not sure how to reset it back to 0 for a new turn so every time after the computer reaches 35 points it will only go once.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class PigGamev1
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int humanScore = 0;
            int computerScore = 0;
            int win = 100;
            int die1 = 0;
            int die2 = 0;
            int total = 0;
            boolean gameOver = false;
            boolean turnOver = false;
            char repeat = 'r';
            String input;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();


do
{

    //human rolls dice
    do
    {
        die1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1;
        die2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1;
        total = die1 + die2;

        if(total == 2)
        {
            humanScore += 0;
            System.out.println("You rolled a: " + total);
            System.out.println("Turn over.");
            System.out.println("Your current score is " + humanScore);
            turnOver = true;
        }
        else if(humanScore <= win && total != 2)
        {
        humanScore += total;
        System.out.println("You rolled a: " + total);
        if(humanScore >= win)
        {
            System.out.println("Your score is " + humanScore + " and my score is "
                    + computerScore);
            System.out.println("You win!");
            turnOver = true;
            gameOver = true;
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Your current score is " + humanScore);
        System.out.println("Enter r to roll again or h to hold.");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        repeat = input.charAt(0);
        if(repeat == 'r')
        {
            turnOver=false;
        }
        else if(repeat == 'h')
        {
            System.out.println("Turn over.");
            System.out.println("Your current score is " + humanScore +
                    " total computer score is " + computerScore + "\n");
            turnOver = true;
        }
        }
    }while(turnOver == false);

    //computer rolls dice
    System.out.println("My turn! \n");

    do
    {
        turnOver = false;
        die1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1;
        die2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(6) + 1;
        total = die1 + die2;
        System.out.println("I rolled a: " + total);

        if(total == 2)
        {
            computerScore += 0;
            System.out.println("Turn over.");
            System.out.println("My current score is " + computerScore + "\n");
            turnOver = true;
        }

        else
        {
            computerScore += total;
            System.out.println("My current score is " + computerScore + "\n");
            if(computerScore >= 35)
            {
                System.out.println("I hold.");
                System.out.println("Your turn!\n");
                System.out.println("My current score is " + computerScore +
                        " your score is " + humanScore + "\n");
                turnOver = true;
            }
        }

        if(computerScore >= win)
        {
            System.out.println("I win!");
            turnOver = true;
            gameOver = true;
            System.exit(0);
        }


    }while(turnOver == false);

}while(gameOver == false);
keyboard.close();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different variables to keep track of the total score for the computer and the score it has on their current turn.  For instance, you could define `int computerTurn;` with the rest of your variables, and use it as such in your program, remembering to reset it to 0 when the turn ends:

```
//some code omitted if not relevant to your problem
do
{
    if(total == 2)
    {
        computerScore += computerTurn;  //adds current turn to running total
        System.out.println("Turn over.");
        System.out.println("My current score is " + computerScore + "\n");
        turnOver = true;
    }

    else
    {
        computerTurn+= total;
        System.out.println("My current score is " + computerScore + "\n");
        if(computerTurn >= 35) //checks against current turn instead of total
        {
            computerScore += computerTurn; //adds current turn to running total
            System.out.println("I hold.");
            System.out.println("Your turn!\n");
            System.out.println("My current score is " + computerScore + 
                " your score is " + humanScore + "\n");
            turnOver = true;
        }
    }
}while(turnOver == false);
computerTurn = 0;
```

Comment: thank you, this works for the most part just when I run it says in the else statement "my current score is 0" the first turn. Shows the correct score at the end of the turn but then shows that score for each roll after until the turn is over. Is there anyway to have it show the correct current score for each roll?

Comment: ignore the previous comment but this also makes my win statement execute after like 2 more rolls happen its probably adding to 35 again and not executing the win statement until it gets to 35 but I need it to execute as soon as the score reaches 100

Comment: In that case, add computerTurn into computerScore before the if statement, and make that if statement check for either turn over 35 OR total over 100.

Comment: else 
       {
           computerTurn+= total;
     computerScore += computerTurn;
           if(computerTurn >= 35 || total >= 100) //checks against current turn instead of total
           {
                //adds current turn to running total
               System.out.println("I hold.");
               System.out.println("Your turn!\n");
               System.out.println("My current score is " + computerScore + 
                   " your score is " + humanScore + "\n");
               turnOver = true;
           }
       }